# Qt5. QSqlQuery, MySQL 8 & json field type

Tags: mysql, json, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

I am using Qt5 with a MySQL 8 database. As far as I know, mysql 8 has new features, it is a json field type. But when I try to get data with columns with json datatype, QSqlQuery.next() method always returns false. Does the QMYSQL driver support the MySQL JSON datatype?

This is a table:

```
create table s_salary_shift (f_id integer primary key auto_increment, f_formula json);
insert into s_salary_shift(f_formula, '{"fixed":5000}'
```

This code returns empty result set:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("cafe5");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("******");
    if (!db.open()) {
        return;
    }
    QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(db);
    q->prepare("select f_formula from s_salary_shift where f_id=:f_id");
    q->bindValue(":f_id", 1);
    q->exec();
    if (q->next()) {
        qDebug() << q->value(0);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Empty result";
    }
```

But if i change query to

```
q->prepare("select cast(f_formula as char) from s_salary_shift where f_id=:f_id");
```

everything works.

Comment: I have tested and it works, could you provide an [MRE]

Comment: Today I ran into this problem again. I noticed that if I directly use q->exec(), without q->prepare () the code working. So, I can work with json field type without prepared statements.